# performing distinct query in MongoDB generates error : distinct too big, 16mb cap MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I recently started learning on MongoDB, and I am trying to query a database, by getting the count of distinct values of column, called `universal` from a specific collection called `linkedin`.

A similar sql query to this would be :
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(universal)) FROM linkedin WHERE universal IS NOT NULL`

I used the following command using DISTINCT :

`db.linkedin.distinct('universal', {'universal' : {'$ne': null}}).length`

I tried the same for a database which wasn't really big,it worked. But I realised it gives an error for a huge database when I run: `distinct too big, 16mb cap`

I did some reading on it,I could use .aggregate instead of .distinct, I didn't get a clear idea how to arrange the .aggregate query to perform the same query I performed with distinct.

Could I get some help on this or if there is is a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two different ways you can find the number of distinct values using aggregation:

```
db.linkedin.aggregate([
  { $match: { universal: { $ne: null } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$universal" } },
  { $count: "universal_count" }
])
```

and

```
db.linkedin.aggregate([
  { $match: { universal: { $ne: null } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$universal" } },
  { $group: { _id: null, universal_count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } }
])
```

The first pipeline makes use of the [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) stage which is only available for versions `>= 3.4`, but they both accomplish the same thing.

The result will be a single document containing a `universal_count` field, which is the number of distinct `universal` values.

### Explanation

The first stage, [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) will select documents with a non-null `universal` field.

The second stage, [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) will group together documents with the same value for `_id`. Since the `_id` field is unique, using the value of  `universal` as the `_id` will create one document per distinct `universal` value.

The `$count` stage is equivalent to the last two `$group` and `$project` stages, so I'll explain those.

The third `$group` stage then takes each document from the previous stage and groups it into a single document because the `_id` for this stage is `null`. The [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator is used to count the number of input documents as the `universal_count` field.

Finally, the [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage removes the `_id` field from the output, leaving just the `universal_count` field.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I really appreciate this